# Create dynamic amount of tables inside a tabsetpanel R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an dynamic amount of datatables inside a tabsetPanel argument. Thanks to various different posts here I came to this 'not working solution'.

The tables are rendered and accesed correctly but the tabsetPanel fails to create and I'm wondering how I can make this work, any help appreciated:

```
library(DT)

# for simplification this is not dynamic but created without hardcoded variable calls.

  portalData <- lapply(1:10,function(x)data.frame(rnorm(5,1))
  names(portalData) <- 1:10


shinyApp(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(    

  headerPanel("Dynamic number of tables inside tabpanels"),            
  sidebarPanel(
  ),            
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tables")
  )
),

server = function(input, output) {

observe({

  output$tables <- renderUI({

    names_list <- lapply(seq_along(portalData), function(i){
      tablename <- paste(names(portalData)[i])
      tabPanel(dataTableOutput(tablename))
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel,do.call(tagList, names_list))

  })

  for(i in 1:length(portalData)){
    local({
      i2 <- i
      output[[names(portalData)[i2]]] <- renderDataTable({portalData[[i2]]})
    })
  }

})

})
```

Comment: Is this considered resolved? Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, problem still exists. Did not figure out how to place tabPanel around the data tables.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic number of tabPanels, each of them holding a table?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not sure I'm on the right track though..

Comment: You are, but there is one Problem: `tabPanel` needs a title value, otherwise it doesn't get recognized as tab. So try out `tabPanel(paste0("tab-", i), dataTableOutput(tablename))` or something similar.

Comment: @K.Rohde is correct. After adding a name, it works.

Comment: It works! Thank you K. Rohde, you can post this as an answer if you want to.